# how to create horizontal scrollable buttons list in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new to android.i want to create dynamic horizontal buttons list with scrollbar  using arrya list in android.ie source.when i press the button want to get the position of the button.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe your talking about is a `HorizontalListView`. There are library projects already created that you can use in your project [Try these out.](https://github.com/search?q=android%20horizontallistview&type=&ref=simplesearch)